# How to create a Graphql implementation in a specific programming language?

Tags: graphql, programming-languages, implementation, specifications

Graphql specification has been implemented in many programming languages, but there is not implementation for my programming language of interest. I wonder how were those implementations created? Any reference materials or tutorials, beside the specification itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the [specification](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/) itself, the Facebook team created [graphql-js](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js) as a reference implementation for other languages.

You can check out https://graphql.org/code/ to see all of the languages which have implemented GraphQL and use those for reference as well!

Comment: Hi Rohit, I was kind of hoping for some tutorial about the implementation. It is hard for me to reserve engineering the source code of graphql.js...